# How to automate html header creation of small website with Webpack?

Tags: html

I want to build a simple static website with pages like Introduction, Getting Started, Download, FAQ. There would be a navigation links at the top too. It's the basic layout you see everywhere.

[What I have done a year ago](http://exceed7.com/introloop/) is just a copy and paste. So every .html page would have the same tab code.

```html
<nav class="text-center">
    <a href="index.html">Introduction</a> |
    <a href="getting-started.html">Getting Started</a> |
    <a href="reference.html">Reference</a> | 
    <a href="demo.html">Demo</a> |
    <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
    <span id="get"><a href="https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#!/content/51095" target="_blank">Get Introloop</a></span>
    <br>
</nav>
```

And then there are a lot of heads, that is *almost* the same but a little bit different from page to page.

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<meta name="keywords" content="Introloop - Easily play looping music with intro section. (Unity plugin)"/>

<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Introloop - Demo"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Let's see how well it performs by yourself!">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.exceed7.com/introloop/demo.html"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.exceed7.com/introloop/img/HeaderImage.png"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Introloop" />

    <title>Introloop - Easily play looping music with intro section (Unity Plugin)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
```

Reading the code I wrote a year ago I feel like it's not good for maintainability. I am considering redoing the site so I would like the current state of doing this. But I can't seems to get the solution from Google search because it is difficult to get the correct search query...

Surely nowadays we use some kind of build tools and I am very interested in learning Webpack. I am wondering what is the usual workflow to make this kind of a small templated website?

Other tools I would like to incorporate is npm + Babel + cssnext + any Bootstrap alternatve + no Gulp, just in case they overlap with the possible solution. The reason for no Bootstrap and no Gulp is that I have been using them for long time and would like to explore other alternatives, which I guess would be available by now

Also looking at Vue.js / Semantic UI / UIKit, all completely new to me. But Vue.js looks too much like React, which my website is just a general information website and does not seems to need any live JS to DOM update..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find an elegant solution with Webpack. It's [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). For each JS `entry` it could generate a separate HTML with `chunk` option. This would be each of my page.

```
chunks: [page],
filename: page + ".html"
```

Each page would be generated with a default template. I will override it with my own [EJS](http://ejs.co/) file that is unique for each page.

```
template: "path/" + page + ".ejs"
```

Using EJS I could write an `<%- include otherejs %>` on each page for common parts to make a template system easily.

Finally setup the loader for all `.ejs` file to be

```
test: /\.ejs$/, 
use: ['html-loader','ejs-html-loader']
```

The first one reads EJS and immediately renders them to HTML. Make sure not to use `ejs-compiled-loader` as that one exports a template funtion that needs to be called again to output HTML. `html-loader` cannot accept a function. This rule will be a loader for `html-webpack-plugin`

One final thing that `html-webpack-plugin` will do is injecting the bundle `<script>` tag which you could control where it is via `inject:` option. I use `head` because I need to hide my page and then play an animation later, I need to have the script ready before the DOM. (Then in script I could use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',afterLoad)`.

I also got live reloading from Webpack's dev server so I am very content with this as a way to develop a small multi-page website. Also it's quite JS-ish, it's good that I don't have to learn any new concept other than Webpack. (When I tried Jekyll I had to face with folder structures rules, front matter, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a static site generator like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com). It will allow you to create parts of the website that should be reused (like a header) and when you build the site it will put all the pieces together.

I know you said Webpack, but that is *not* the tool for this job. I would highly recommend not compiling HTML together with Webpack or even Gulp. Those are for building things like Sass and JavaScript.